# Is there a auto-conversion from String to ByteString?

Tags: haskell

```
addRequestHeader (H.hContentType, "application/json")
```

this is a example of the usage of Network.HTTP.Simple package, i have seen a couple of times. how does that work to pass a String to that function as its signature is:

```
addRequestHeader :: Network.HTTP.Types.Header.HeaderName
 -> Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString -> Request -> Request
```

when i try this, i get the error **couldn't match expected type ‘C8.ByteString’ with actual type ‘[Char]’**, so i have to use **Data.ByteString.Char8.pack** function to make this work. why don't the others have to do that? is there a auto-convertion or whats going on here?

Comment: Haskell has no autoconversions in general. All conversions are done *explicitly*.

Comment: @carcigenicate no there is only this one with ByteString http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.3.2/docs/Network-HTTP-Simple.html#v:addRequestHeader

Comment: You may perhaps use the [`{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-OverloadedStrings) language extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an "autoconversion" for string *literals*, i.e. for those strings given explicitly between quotes `"..."`, like your `"application/json"`.

To turn it on you need the [`OverloadedStrings`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=overloaded#extension-OverloadedStrings) extension.

Other string expressions (e.g., variables of type `String`, return values of functions, ...) will not be automatically converted.

Comment: thx. thats it. i checked that. it only works with static-string-literals not with string-variables. 

Comment: @stefang with string-variables you generally want to be more specific than "convert to a bytestring" since there are several different incompatible ways to do that (not a Haskell problem: it's just more visible in Haskell since it's one of the older languages to use unicode strings by default)